# Read/Write using FileChannel and FileInput/OutputStream-Java

Tags: java, io, filechannel

I am new to file handling. I tried reading a file using fileinputstream and file channel. I could not find out the bug in the following code. It runs successfully but file has not been transferred. New file is created with zero bytes. Please have a look at the code and check what went wrong

```
public class FileTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        try {
            File file = new File("sss.jpg");
            FileChannel inChannel=new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
            //FileChannel inChannel = in.getChannel();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
            while(inChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
                FileChannel outChannel=new FileOutputStream("sss1.jpg",true).getChannel();
                outChannel.write(buffer);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this,

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Test_Stuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        String thisFile = "Test.java";
        FileInputStream source = new FileInputStream(thisFile);
        FileOutputStream destination = new FileOutputStream("Output.java");
        FileChannel sourceFileChannel = source.getChannel();
        FileChannel destinationFileChannel = destination.getChannel();
        long size = sourceFileChannel.size();
        sourceFileChannel.transferTo(0, size, destinationFileChannel);
    }
}
```

Comment: `transferTo()` needs to be called in a loop. It isn't guaranteed to complete the entire transfer in a single operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(inChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
    FileChannel outChannel=new FileOutputStream("sss1.jpg",true).getChannel();
    outChannel.write(buffer);
}
```

1. You're creating a new file each time around the loop. OK you're appending but this is not efficient, and you're never closing it.
2. You forgot to flip and compact the buffer.

   ```
   FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream("sss1.jpg").getChannel();
   while(inChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
       buffer.flip();
       outChannel.write(buffer);
       buffer.compact();
   }
   outChannel.close();
   inChannel.close();
   ```

Comment: Thank you. The buffer is bytebuffer but flip is the method of class buffer. Does it go well with bytebuffer class?. Is it even possible? can u explain?

Comment: @Struse look at the javadoc and/or the source code. there's a relationship between `ByteBuffer` and `Buffer`. look at the class signatures first.

Comment: @djeikyb I saw them. Sorry i missed the listed inherited method from buffer class right at the bottom. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely follow [EJP's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33602351/659715) or [Achintha Gunasekara's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33602299/659715) answer. You are doing multiple things poorly (eg, creating many output channels, not using [`FileChannel::open`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-), etc). But I believe the essential problem is not calling [`flip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip--). From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip--):

> Flips this buffer. The limit is set to the current position and then
>   the position is set to zero. If the mark is defined then it is
>   discarded. After a sequence of channel-read or put operations, invoke
>   this method to prepare for a sequence of channel-write or relative get
>   operations. For example:
>
> ```
>  buf.put(magic);    // Prepend header
>  in.read(buf);      // Read data into rest of buffer
>  buf.flip();        // Flip buffer
>  out.write(buf);    // Write header + data to channel
> ```
>
> This method is often used in conjunction with the compact method when
>   transferring data from one place to another.

Comment: Nothing wrong with checking via `> 0` in blocking mode: `read()` can't return zero unless there is no space in the buffer, which would be a programming error you wouldn't want to spin-loop on. Using the `Files` object isn't compulsory.

Comment: @EJP that's a fair point, hadn't thought of it, thanks. i wasn't thinking of it as an error, per se, more just that the javadoc says `-1` signals end of stream, so should use that. but now i'll use `> 0` with your comment in mind.